# Return single true from function in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm having a bit of trouble getting my function to return a single `true` or `false`

Basically I have an array like below;

`orderItem` contains `menu_modifier_groups` which contains `menu_modifier_items`

Now each `menu_modifier_groups` has an attribute `max_selection_points`.
The `menu_modifier_items` are displayed using `ng-repeat` with `checkboxes` and have an `ng-model = item.selected`

What I want to do is to be able to loop through all `menu_modifier_groups` and determine if the required `menu_modifier_items` have been selected by comparing them to `max_selection_points` of each `menu_modifier_groups`

This is what I have so far

```
$scope.isValid = function (orderItem) {
        var count = 0;
        angular.forEach(orderItem.menu_modifier_groups, function(group) {
            angular.forEach(group.menu_modifier_items, function (item) {
             count += item.selected ? 1 : 0;
        });
        if (count != group.max_selection_points) {
            return false;
        } else if (count == group.max_selection_points) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Any help/advice appreciated

Comment: you should have single `if` condition out side of all `forEach`

Comment: @ParthTrivedi but then `group` will be outside scope and will not be defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be

```
$scope.isValid = function(orderItem) { 
  //By default make it false
  var IsAllSelected = false;
  angular.forEach(orderItem.menu_modifier_groups, function(group) {
    var count = 0;                
    angular.forEach(group.menu_modifier_items, function(item) {
      count += item.selected ? 1 : 0;
    });
    if (count == group.max_selection_points) {
      IsAllSelected = true;
    } else {
      //if one item failed All select do return false
      IsAllSelected = false;
    }
  });
  return IsAllSelected;
}
```

Comment: getting `IsAllSelected is not defined` also you have `count` and `Count`